# Error message during start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, acpi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 as a frsh installation in my Lenovo IdeaPad 320-14lkb. The operating system installed and running basic tasks well. But during start up every time there are several following error messages.

[    0.354302] platform MSFT0101:00 failed to claim resource 1: [ mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
[    0.354316] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[    0.437177] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_PR.CPU0._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730psargs-330)
[    0.437223] ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.CPU1._CPC due to previous error(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)

and so on....

How can I get rid of this? is it a boot problem (GPT/MBR) or something else? Please check the attachment please. I need to go for this OS and version, I am working on different application that works with this OS version.
Error message from the pc][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFbWT.jpg)

Comment: Search on this site for for "ACPI Error" for me the first result links to a duplicate with information/answer.

Comment: If the system otherwise starts and runs well, your best bet probably is to ignore these.